# Remove common objects between two List considering the number of occurrences

Tags: java, list, array-intersect

Say I have two Java ArrayList and I want to find the difference between two lists, considering the count of each element.
For example in above lists, the difference will be an `a` since `list_1` has one extra `a`:

```
list_1 = ["a", "a", "b"]
list_2 = ["a", "b"]
diff = ["a"]
```

I tried to do this by a simple for loop but got `concurrent modification exception` or invalid result.
I also tried to find the common elements using `retain` and remove them from each list but it fails for example in the following scenario:

```java
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of("a","a"));

List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of("a"));

List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(l1);
ret.retainAll(l2);

// ret will be ["a", "a"] and not ["a"]
```

sample loop that doesn't work:

```java
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of("b", "a"));

List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of("a", "b", "a"));

for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
    if (l2.contains(l1.get(i))) {
        l1.remove(l1.get(i));
        l2.remove(l1.get(i));
    }

// incorrect result: l1: ["a"] , l2: ["a", "b"]
// expected result: l1:[] , l2: ["a"]
```

**Update**
Updated the loop based on Turing85 comment which seems to work:

```java
for (int i = l1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i < l1.size() && l2.contains(l1.get(i))) {
        l2.remove(l1.get(i));
        l1.remove(l1.get(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I tried to do this by a simple for loop but got `concurrent modification exception`*"- Then you probably used a `foreach`-loop, not a "regular" `for`-loop.

Comment: I updated the post with my implementation

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If we remove an element from `l1`, we also have to decrement `i` by `1`. Furthermore, with the current implementation we must remove the element from `l2` before we remove it from `l1`.

Comment: Thank you @Turing85. Updated the question with your comment. I think we also can start from the last element of the list to avoid indeoutofbound

Comment: hmm can you explain why i should incremented (or decremented)? is that because we will ignore one element in the middle if we don't do this?

Comment: Is it important that a) the algorithm runs in-place (i.e. lists `l1` and `l2` are modified) and b) the `String`s stay in the same order?

Comment: No, we can sort later or create new Lists

Comment: In this case, I would suggest to create a `Map<String, Integer>` for each `input`-map, counting the frequency of each entry and then calculate the difference based on those maps. Might be a little bit more understandable.

Comment: Turing85 would you checkout the updated loop? I cannot find a case that this might not work.

Comment: Loop looks fine to me.

Comment: Here's an [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/IIGhNT) to my proposal.